# What is the earliest source containing the music for Adoro te devote?

Tags: reference-request, thomas-aquinas, music, hymns

Can someone point me to the earliest source that contains the melody for *Adoro te devote*?  I've checked on the Cantus Index, as well as MMMO database and have not been able to find anything on this hymn.  I want to view the document.  If you don't know the earliest one, can you point me to an early one?  I'm guessing it would be 18<sup>th</sup> century.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lyrics for [***Adoro te devote***](https://www.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Adoro_te_devote) were composed by St. Thomas Aquinas. CPDL says the following about this hymn:

> [Eucharistic hymn](https://www.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Category:Eucharistic_songs) (Meter [11 11. 11 11](https://www.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Category:11_11._11_11)) attributed to [Thomas Aquinas](https://www.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Thomas_Aquinas), with notable English versions by J. R. Woodford (whose version is in [10 10. 10 10](https://www.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Category:10_10._10_10) meter), [John Mason Neale](https://www.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/John_Mason_Neale) and [Gerard Manley Hopkins](https://www.cpdl.org/wiki/index.php/Gerard_Manley_Hopkins). The traditional tune appears in the [1697 *Processionale Parisiense* pp. 192-3](https://books.google.com/books?id=kC1dVuVAu1UC&pg=PA192).

[image: Processionale Parisiense p. 192]
[image: Processionale Parisiense p. 193]

See Torrell, O.P., [*Saint Thomas Aquinas (vol. 1): The Person and His Work*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5927), ch. VII, § "The Office of *Corpus Christi*", §§ "The *Adoro te*" for details about its authenticity.

Comment: thanks for the information.  i'm mainly asking about the tune.  i want to look at an early source that contains the melody.  i read about that 1697 Processionale, but i don't know where to find it.

Comment: @R.B.Jawad I added some scans of the processional.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much.

Comment: would you mind posting the rest of the hymn?

Comment: @R.B.Jawad That's all I saw.

Comment: ok, thanks, i appreciate it.